# how can I save right-to-left sheet in r when I use openxlsx library?

Tags: r, openxlsx

I use openxlsx library and I want to save my xlsx file,
but I want to save all the sheet right to left (not just the cells diriction)
how can I do it?
tnx!

I want to do like the picture below, but in R:
[image]

Comment: you can't order the way you want it when writing the data to the worksheet?

Comment: how? I dont want to order to column, I want to change sheet's direction